# Why does my code of computing Greatest Common Divisor of multiple integers return nothing?

Tags: java, arrays, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote the following codes to calculate gcd of unspecified number of integers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] list = new int[5];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    
    gcd(list);
}

// Get the gcd of multiple integers
public static void gcd(int...numbers) {
    int gcd = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        gcd = gcdOfTwo(gcd, numbers[i]);
    }
    
System.out.println("The gcd is: " + gcd);

}

// Get the gcd of two integers
public static int gcdOfTwo(int a, int b) {
    int gcdOfTwo = 1;
    int possibleGcd = 1;
    
    while (gcdOfTwo <= a && gcdOfTwo <= b) {
        if (a % possibleGcd == 0 && b % possibleGcd == 0) {
            gcdOfTwo = possibleGcd;
            possibleGcd++;
        }
    }
    
    return gcdOfTwo;
}

}
```

My thought is to get the gcd of two numbers (say it's GCD), and get the gcd of GCD and the third number, and so on and so forth.

The problem looks like "gcd(list)" isn't working correctly. After I enter all the integers, and press enter key, nothing happens.

--- update ---

I've moved possibleGcd++ out of if statement, but it still has something wrong as the console gave me this:

```
Enter a number: 
1
Enter a number: 
2
Enter a number: 
3
Enter a number: 
4
Enter a number: 
5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.gcdOfTwo(GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.java:35)
at GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.gcd(GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.java:22)
at GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.main(GcdOfUnspecifiedNumberOfIntegers.java:14)
```

---

#### Solved

I should use while (possibleGcd <= a && possibleGcd <= b) instead of while (gcdOfTwo <= a && gcdOfTwo <= b).

Comment: what about put a breakpoint to see what happens?

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: You may want to use `while (gcdOfTwo <= a/2 && gcdOfTwo <= b/2)` since the **gcd** is always less than or equal to **a/2** and **b/2**. your code will run faster

Comment: @VinodJayachandran I'm new to java, and I don't know much about debugging. I guess I'll understand the problem better in the future:)

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop to this :

```
while (possibleGcd <= a && possibleGcd <= b) {
    if (a % possibleGcd == 0 && b % possibleGcd == 0) {
        gcdOfTwo = possibleGcd;
    }
    possibleGcd++;
}
```

Comment: Good start - also need to start gcd at numbers[0] rather than 1 'cause gcd of 1 and anything is 1.

Answer (score 0):

this loop:

```
while (gcdOfTwo <= a && gcdOfTwo <= b) {
    if (a % possibleGcd == 0 && b % possibleGcd == 0) {
        gcdOfTwo = possibleGcd;
        possibleGcd++;
    }
}
```

runs infinetely since you not increase `gcdOfTw` (in case you dont get inside if  `gcdOfTwo = possibleGcd` and  `possibleGcd++` is never executed)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (gcdOfTwo <= a && gcdOfTwo <= b) {
    if (a % possibleGcd != 0 || b % possibleGcd != 0) {
        break;
    }
    gcdOfTwo = possibleGcd;
    possibleGcd++;
}
```